# MAMP (PRO) 6 how can I export hosts configuration?

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I moved from Intel Mac to M1 and after upgrading I can't kill MySQL anymore, I also have MAMP server randomly restarting

I would like to do a fresh install the only hard think would be recreate all my host structure ( not files and DB )

I know MAMP Pro has a backup utility but ( for me ) it is useless since it try to backup the entire host with all files

What I need to backup is only web server configuration, but can't find any info about that